# unable to swap rows in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join

I have the below table where names will be inserted first. Then I will get IDs where I need to map with names

```
     ID  NAME
    null   Test1
    null    Test2
    1      null
    2      null
```

[image: here]

I need the result like

```
ID  NAME
1    Test1
2    Test2
```

I tried below query but it doesn't work for me

```
select t1.ID , t2.Name from table1 T1 join table1 t2 on T1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i need to replace nulls with the data. @JohnWoo I updated my Q please check once

Comment: In your query "select t1" is not capital T. Does this fix the problem?

Comment: How to you decide which id value to match with which name?

Comment: which sql dialect? What product are you using? Please add the specific tag

Comment: your image shows a result, not a table, so is the source really a table, or the result of another query? If it is the result of another query, you need to show the original table structure and the query that led to the result with the two off set nulls.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: @jarlh it's like first i will get all the names inserted into Name column and then i will get id's . so 1st name should map with first ID and so on.

Comment: @harish Please define `first` name. how do you determine which one is the first one? By default, there is no specific order in SQL Server unless, you explicitly specify the `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to screen short you are working with SQL Server , you could try `cte` expression which may help you

```
;with cte as
(
    select max(id) id, row_number() over (order by (select 1)) rn from
    ( 
       select *, rank() over(order by id) rnk from table
    ) a
    group by a.rnk 
    having max(id) is not null
), cte1 as
(
    select max(name) name, row_number() over (order by (select 1)) rn from
    ( 
       select *, rank() over(order by name) rnk from table
    ) a
    group by a.rnk 
    having max(name) is not null
)
select c.id, c1.name from cte c
join cte1 c1 on c1.rn = c.rn
```

**Result :**

```
id  name
1   test1
2   test2
```